# Degree $2015$ polynomial value at $2016$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I was doing this question from an RMO Practice Paper, and I have been unable to solve it.

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $2015$. $P(k)=2^k$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots,2015$. Find $P(2016)$

My attempt:

Let $Q(x)=P(x)-2^x$.

Then its zeroes are $0,1,2,\dots,2015$. Thus $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2015$ with $2016$ zeroes. Therefore it is always $0$, thus giving $P(x)=2^x$, so $P(2016)=2^{2016}$, but the answer is given as $2^{2016}-1$.

Where did I go wrong and how do I get the correct answer?

Please help.

Comment: Your $Q(x)$ is not a polynomial

Comment: Q is not a polynomial

Comment: @Vasya Why not?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo: because of $2^x$

Comment: Similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177129/find-the-value-of-the-polynomial-at-a-given-point

Comment: If you think that $Q(x)$ is a polynomial: what is its degree? What is the degree of $x^{2015}-2^x$? of $x^2-2015^x$? of $x^x$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the value of the polynomial at a given point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177129/find-the-value-of-the-polynomial-at-a-given-point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using repeated differences, we get that the first value in every row is $1$:
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & \cdots \\
1 & 2 & 4 & \cdots \\
1 & 2 & \cdots \\
1 & \cdots \\
\cdots \\
1 & \\
\end{array}
$$
[Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series) then gives
$$
P(n)= 
1 \binom{n}{0} + 1 \binom{n}{1} + 1 \binom{n}{2} + \cdots = \sum_{k=0}^{2015} \binom{n}{k}
$$
Therefore,
$$
P(2016) = \sum_{k=0}^{2015} \binom{2016}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{2016} \binom{2016}{k} - \binom{2016}{2016} = 2^{2016}-1
$$

Comment: What do you mean by repeated differences?

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo, see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is wrong because $Q(x)$ is not a polynomial due to the presence of $2$ to the power $x$.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to downvote this. OP originally just asked "Where did I go wrong?", and this post answers that original question completely. OP later added "and how do I get the correct answer?"

Comment: @PersonX I agree. The reason given is exactly why the answer is wrong, and you're right the OP later added "and how do I get the correct answer?" after Dr. N.Padmanabhan's answer. I reformatted the answer Dr. N.Padmanabhan, hope this is ok.

Answer (score 2):

From the calculus of finite differences, the leading coefficient of $P(x)$
is
$$a=\frac1{2015!}\sum_{j=0}^{2015}(-1)^j\binom{2015}jf(2015-j)
=\frac1{2015!}\sum_{j=0}^{2015}(-1)^j\binom{2015}j2^{2015-j}
=\frac{(2-1)^{2015}}{2015!}$$
etc.

Consider now $Q(x)=P(x+1)-2P(x)$. This also has degree $2015$, leading
coefficient $-a$.
and $P(0)=P(1)=\cdots=P(2014)=0$. Therefore
$Q(x)=-ax(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2014)$
and then $Q(2015)=P(2016)-2^{2016}=-2015!a$ etc.